# Initialize XMLSerialize ahead of time to save from run time cost

Tags: c#, windows-mobile

I have a bunch of typed xmlserialize object:

```
class Serializer{

        static XmlSerializer serializerRequest_EnterVehicle = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Request_EnterVehicle));
        static XmlSerializer serializerRequest_Cancel = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Request_Cancel));
        static XmlSerializer serializerRequest_PrintInfo = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Request_PrintInfo));

    public string ObjToXML(object toSerialize)...
}
```

Instead of having these created at runtime, I would like to have them initialized at application start
These are part of a Serializer class, I am not sure of this is a good approach? Is there a better way to do this sort of initialization, is there any other cost associated with this?

Am I correct in the assumption that this initialization cost is done only once by using the static keyword?

Edit: The project is a .NET 3.5 Compact Framework project for a windows mobile 6.1 Pro device.

UPDATED:

```
using System;

using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace SmartDevice_Proxy
{
    public sealed class TypedXMLSerializers
    {
        private static volatile TypedXMLSerializers instance;
        private static object syncRoot = new Object();

        //Implementation as Singleton
        static XmlSerializer serializerRequest_EnterVehicle = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Request_EnterVehicle));
        static XmlSerializer serializerRequest_Cancel = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Request_Cancel));
        static XmlSerializer serializerRequest_PrintInfo = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Request_PrintInfo));

        private TypedXMLSerializers() { }

        public static TypedXMLSerializers Instance
        {
            get
            {
                if (instance == null)
                {
                    lock (syncRoot)
                    {
                        if (instance == null)
                            instance = new TypedXMLSerializers();
                    }
                }

                return instance;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Need to test this for thread safety.

Comment: Are you experiencing a performance problem by instancing them when they're needed?

Comment: Yes one of them has an overhead of 100 ms just one line of code, it's not usable.

Answer (score 1):

You can implement singleton pattern

Link : http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/singleton.html

Comment: Unfortunatly I think Lazy is out of question since this has to compile on .net 3.5 CF

Comment: on 3.5 Lazy don't exist , but in this case i suggest singleton in order to instanciate  just one instance, Thank's Adam

Comment: Indeed that is what I am questioning if I should or not do, since i can have multiple threads instantiating.

Comment: you can add volatile to your singleton in this case of multi threading.link : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650316.aspx

Comment: Cool Thanks for the tip, I will try this approach!

Comment: I'am happy to help you Adam

Answer (score 0):

The answer is yes, if those `XmlSerializer`s variables are not static, then everytime you will initiate your class `class Serializer` they will be initialized for that class.

When they are static, they will not necessarily be initialized at application start, they will only be initialized once when any static or no-static member (function or variable) in the `class Serializer` is called for the first time.

If you will have only one single instance of `class Serializer` during the whole course of the application, then it will make no real difference if you set them as `static` or non-static.

**Edit:**

Based on your scenario you might be interested in this:

[Implementing Singleton in C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650316.aspx)

Comment: I do have a singleton for another object, bit there can be multiple instances of serializer since I can have multiple threads doing serialization. I am now questioning if XmlSerializer should be encapsulated in it's own singleton class.

Comment: @AdamSurfari I do not think accessing the same `XmlSerializer` object from different threads concurrently is safe, you should do syncronization using `lock`/`Monitor`/`Mutex`/..etc

Answer (score 0):

Making them static will have the instances created the first time the class is used in your code. The the only additional overhead in doing this is that the memory will be used the entire time that your application is running. With only a few instances of this class, the performance increase would greatly outweigh this small memory usage.

Additionally you can have the serialization assemblies generated at compile time. In your c# project go to **Properties** and then the **Build** tab. Near the bottom is the **generate serialization assemblies** option. This will use the sgen.exe tool to precompile your `XmlSerializer` assemblies. Something that is done at runtime if not done at compile time.

[project setting documentation on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kb4wyys2%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I could not find that option in my project, perhaps this is not available for Smart Device Project / Windows Mobile projects.

Comment: I'm not familiar with windows mobile. So perhaps.